# Finite Element Method and implementation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, variational-analysis

I'm studying this problem:

$$
\begin{equation}
\left (\mathcal P\right ) \quad \begin{cases}\label{P}
-u''(x) = f(x), \quad \text{sur} \quad I = ]0,1[\\
u'(0) = 1 \\
u(1) = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

where

$$
f(x) = H\left(x-\frac{1}{2} \right), \quad \text{H = Heaviside function}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
-u'(x) & = (x-1/2)H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) + c_1, \quad u'(0) = 1 \implies c_1 = 1 \\
& = \frac{1}{2}(2x-1)H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) + 1
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\int (2x-1)H(x-{1}{2}) \, dx   = \left[ \frac{1}{2}(2x-1)^2H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \right] - \int (2x-1)H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \, dx
$$

$$
\implies \int (2x-1)H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \, dx = \frac{1}{4}(2x-1)^2H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) 
$$

$$
u(x) =  -\frac{1}{8}(2x-1)^2H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) + x + c_2, \quad u(1) = 0 \implies c_2 = -\frac{7}{8}
$$

the exact solution is:

$$
u(x) =  -\frac{1}{8}(2x-1)^2H\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) + x -\frac{7}{8}, \quad  u\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =  \frac{-3}{8}
$$

We know that we need to search the solution in H^1(I) with the boundary conditions. How can i show that it's also in H^2(I)?

Also, at the end with the P1 finite element aproximation,  i have this matrix:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{2}{h}  & -\dfrac{1}{h}  &  0 & \dots & \dots & 0\\
    -\dfrac{1}{h}  & \dfrac{2}{h} & -\dfrac{1}{h}  & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0  &   \ddots     & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    0  &   \ddots     & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots &  0\\
    0 & \dots & \ddots & -\dfrac{1}{h}  & \dfrac{2}{h} & -\dfrac{1}{h}  \\
    0  & \dots & \dots & 0  & -\dfrac{1}{h}  & \dfrac{2}{h} 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

which i easily implemented with in Fortran. I'm wondering how can i implement the source term?

The variational formulation of this problem is $$
\begin {cases}
u\in V, \forall v\in V\\
\int_{0}^{1} u'(x)v'(x)  \, dx  = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)v(x) \, dx  -  v(0)
\end {cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $H^2$-regularity, since the space $V=\{v\in H^1(0,1):v(1)=0\}$, and $C^\infty_0(0,1)\subset V$, from the weak formulation, we immediately get that

$$\int_0^1u'(x)v'(x)=-\int_0^1(-f)v\quad\forall v\in C^\infty_0(0,1),$$

and so $-f$ is the second weak derivative of $u$. Since $-f\in L^2(0,1)$, it follows that $u\in H^2(0,1)$.

For the right-hand side implementation, I assume you have a uniform finite element grid, and that the middle gridpoint lies on the point $x=1/2$, and that the finite element space is piecewise linear. I'm also assuming that $H$ is zero on $[0,1/2)$ and $1$ otherwise.

You then just have to calculate $L(v_i):=\int_0^1 fv_i\,dx-v_i(0)=\int_{1/2}^1v_i\,dx-v_i(0)$ for each linear basis function $v_i$. Interestingly for $v_0$ (the basis function that is $1$ at $x=0$ and $0$ at the first internal gridpoint $x_1=h$, we have $L(v_0) = -v_0(0)=-1$. For all the $v_i$'s that are supported only in $[h,1/2]$, we have $L(v_i)=0$. For the $v_i$ that is $1$ at $x=1/2$, we have $L(v_i) = \int_{1/2}^{1/2+h}v_i = \sqrt{h^2+1}$, then for all the rest of the $v_i$'s $L(v_i)=\int_{1/2}^{1}v_i = 2\sqrt{h^2+1}$ (since we integrate over the full support of $v_i$).